# Showing $\forall q\in\mathcal{P}_Y$ there exists $ p\in\mathcal{P}_X:q\circ A\le p\implies A:X\to Y$ continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, open-map

Let $(X,\mathcal{P}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{P}_Y)$ be locally convex topological vector spaces with topologies induced by the families of continuous seminorms $\mathcal{P}_X$ and $\mathcal{P}_Y$ respectively and let $A:X\to Y$ be a linear map.

I want to show that $A:X\to Y$ is continuous $\iff\forall q\in\mathcal{P}_Y$ there exists $p\in\mathcal{P}_X$ such that $q(A(x))\le p(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

I wanted to first show the $\Longleftarrow$ direction.

**Via the pre-image**

First I tried to do it by claiming that it suffices to show that $A$ is continuous at 0 in $X$. To this end, let $B_q(0,r)$, with $q\in\mathcal{P}_Y$ and $r>0$ be an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $Y$. Then we must show that the pre-image $A^{-1}(B_q(0,r))$ is open in $X$. That is, $A^{-1}(B_q(0,r))=\{x\in X:T(x)\in B_q(0,r)\}$...

However, this seemed a dead-end and I couldn't see how to relate it with the inequality.

**Showing A is bounded**

Next I considered that $A:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $A:X\to Y$ is bounded. And, in a locally convex topological space, $U\subset X$ is bounded if and only if every $p\in\mathcal{P}_X$ is bounded on $U$. Thus, since the topology on $Y$ is induced by $\mathcal{P}_Y$, the map $A:X\to Y$ is bounded if and only if for all $q\in\mathcal{P}_Y$ there exists $p\in\mathcal{P}_X$ such that $q(A(x))\le p(x)$...which would in fact prove the if and only if statement, however, I am not sure if this argument is complete.

I also thought of proving it via some definition of sequential continuity, e.g. $A$ continuous if and only if  $x_n\to 0\implies Ax_n\to 0$, but it seems a little tricky to formulate in this seminorm setting and I don't know if it would be fruitful.

Comment: Are the families of seminorms assumed to be scale-invariant ($p \in \mathcal{P} \land c > 0 \implies c\cdot p \in \mathcal{P}$) and upward filtering (for all $p_1,p_2 \in \mathcal{P}$ there is a $p_3 \in \mathcal{P}$ with $p_3 \geqslant \max \{ p_1,p_2\}$)?

Comment: Also, for general locally convex spaces, boundedness of a linear map does not imply continuity.

Comment: @DanielFischer I should have mentioned that the two families both form fundamental systems of seminorms so that we do indeed have the upward filtering. I am not sure of the "scale-invariance"; is that some kind of absorption condition?

Comment: Without the scale invariance, you need a constant factor, $q(Ax) \leqslant C_{p,q}\cdot p(x)$, like in normed spaces. (It would suffice that for every $p_1$ and $c$ there is a $p_2$ such that $p_2 \geqslant cp_1$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I also thought that we would have the constant factor. The closest thing I have is that if $p$ is any continuous seminorm then there exists a constant $C>0$ and $q\in\widetilde{\mathcal{P}}$ (with $\widetilde{\mathcal{P}}$ a fundamental system of seminorms) such that $p\le Cq$.

Comment: If $\mathcal{P}_X$ is the family of _all_ continuous seminorms on $X$, then we won't need a constant factor. Anyway, if $A$ is continuous and $q$ a continuous seminorm on $Y$, then $q\circ A$ is a continuous seminorm on $X$. And $q(Ax) \leqslant C\cdot p(x)$ implies $A(\{ x : p(x) < r/C\}) \subset \{ y : q(y) < r\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So the idea is that $q\circ A$ a continuous seminorm on $X$ implies that it is bounded by a seminorm on $X$, namely $p\in\mathcal{P}_X$? And if $A(\{x:p(x)<r/C\}\subset\{y:q(y)<r\}$ then $A:X\to Y$ is continuous since it maps bounded sets to bounded sets?

Comment: Depending on what conditions on $\mathcal{P}_X$ we have, it implies that there is a $p\in \mathcal{P}_X$ with $q(Ax) \leqslant Cp(x)$ for some constant $C$, or one with $q(Ax) \leqslant p(x)$. And in the other direction, $A$ is continuous because the preimage of every neighbourhood of $0\in Y$ is a neighbourhood of $0 \in X$.

Comment: It is not the case that "$A$ maps bounded sets to bounded sets" implies the continuity of $A$ for general locally convex spaces. Consider $Y$ an infinite-dimensional normed space, and $X$ the same space endowed with its weak topology. The identity maps bounded sets to bounded sets (every weakly bounded set is norm-bounded), but it is not continuous, since the norm topology is _strictly_ finer than the weak topology. Similarly, sequential continuity does in general not imply continuity.